# Просканировать объект и получить данные

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<div class="response--photo--upload">
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://i.imgur.com/HULaZZP.jpg">
        <div class="d-inline-block upload--photo--view">
            <button class="upload--photo--close">
                <i class="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BnDvdvN.jpg" width="80">
        </div>
    </a>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://i.imgur.com/qtp5Ybs.jpg">
        <div class="d-inline-block upload--photo--view">
            <button class="upload--photo--close">
                <i class="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/e7tsLc8.jpg" width="80">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Есть объект **response--photo--upload** в нем есть множество `<a><img></a>`

Вопрос: Как просканировать родительский объект и получить **href** у **a** и **src** у **img** (для каждого `<a>`) и занести все данные в **JSON**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если надо составить объекты с учетом связанности (вложенности), то сначала перебираете внешние `a`, и для каждой находите внутри `img`. Если надо просто все ресурсы выцепить, то сразу перебираете `a,img` и вытаскиваете атрибуты.
Кодирование в JSON через `JSON.stringify`.
Если исходный фрагмент html приходит в качестве строки то делаете `$(html_string)` и ищите в ней вместо `$(".response___)`

```js
let obj = $(".response--photo--upload");
let result = obj.find("a").map(function(){
               return {
                 href : $(this).attr('href'),
                 src  : $(this).find('img').attr('src')
               };
            }).get();
            
console.log(result);

let result2 = obj.find("a, img")
                 .map((idx,v) => v.href || v.src)
                 .get();
                 
console.log(result2);

//JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="response--photo--upload">
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://i.imgur.com/HULaZZP.jpg">
        <div class="d-inline-block upload--photo--view">            
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BnDvdvN.jpg" width="80">
        </div>
    </a>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://i.imgur.com/qtp5Ybs.jpg">
        <div class="d-inline-block upload--photo--view">            
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/e7tsLc8.jpg" width="80">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```